# Submit Datatable: Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a datatable on my jsp populated by a "java.util.Set" collection that came from a Hibernate search. I want to make this datatable editable and then save the edited table on my database. I'm able to do it if the datatable is formed through List collection object. All my POJO objects are formed with Set Collection and I'm trying to avoid changing all of them.

I'm using Spring MVC and as I told before Hibernate.

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: I'm not able to submit the edited rows into a java.util.Set of my POJO that allows me save the data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's possible to use a Set to display data in a JSP but you can't modify them.
Take a look of this [link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?12914-How-to-bind-a-java-util-Set).